# Getting different msg digests from what seems to be same input

Tags: python, hashlib

Note the following code. I expect the final printed msg digest to be the same as the last one written. But, when I run the following code, I get two different msg digests:

```
b'Hello world!20' -> 0014bcc2a7237e128dd810f8c8b49371860cbd61e112865c6008081a20ba9a0d
b'Hello world!20' -> 69a4104786309d2d98957da1cebba060043118fd5113a12e43ce184a6d06c368
```

Here is the code...

```
import hashlib
m = hashlib.sha256()
for nonce in range(10000):
    msg = b"Hello world!"+str(nonce).encode()
    m.update(msg)
    print(msg,"->", m.hexdigest())
    if m.hexdigest() < "00fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff":
        break
n = hashlib.sha256()
n.update(b"Hello world!20")
print(b"Hello world!20", "->", n.hexdigest())
```

I assume there is some issue with the encoding of the data that's input into the hashlib update.

Comment: You update `m` in a loop. You never reset original `m`. Move `m = hashlib.sha256()` inside loop.

Comment: That's it - thanks